# JFreeChart AreaChart from the middle of chart panel

Tags: java, jfreechart

I have a dynamic Area Chart and I want it to be displayed from the middle of the panel that's mean that i want the data to be added from the middle of the X axis but not from the right of the chart.
I'm working with an example shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048852/using-jfreechart-to-display-recent-changes-in-a-time-series/5048863#5048863) . How to do this?
There's my code:

```
public class essaijfree2 extends ApplicationFrame {

private static final String TITLE = "Dynamic Series";
private static final String START = "Start";
private static final String STOP = "Stop";
private static final float MINMAX = 100;
private static final int COUNT = 2 * 60;
private static final int FAST = 100;
private static final int SLOW = FAST * 5;
private static final Random random = new Random();
private Timer timer;

public essaijfree2(final String title) {
    super(title);
    final DynamicTimeSeriesCollection dataset =
        new DynamicTimeSeriesCollection(1, COUNT, new Second());
    dataset.setTimeBase(new Second(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2011));
    dataset.addSeries(gaussianData(), 0, "Gaussian data");
    JFreeChart chart = createChart(dataset);
    XYPlot xyPlot = (XYPlot) chart.getPlot();
    XYDifferenceRenderer r = new XYDifferenceRenderer(Color.green,Color.red, true);
    xyPlot.setRenderer(r);



    final JComboBox combo = new JComboBox();
    combo.addItem("Fast");
    combo.addItem("Slow");
    combo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if ("Fast".equals(combo.getSelectedItem())) {
                timer.setDelay(FAST);
            } else {
                timer.setDelay(SLOW);
            }
        }
    });

    this.add(new ChartPanel(chart), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    JPanel btnPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());

    btnPanel.add(combo);
    this.add(btnPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    timer = new Timer(FAST, new ActionListener() {

        float[] newData = new float[1];

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            newData[0] = randomValue();
            dataset.advanceTime();
            dataset.appendData(newData);
        }
    });
}

private float randomValue() {

    return (float) (random.nextGaussian() * MINMAX / 3);
}

private float[] gaussianData() {
    float[] a = new float[COUNT];
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        a[i] = randomValue();
    }
    return a;
}

private JFreeChart createChart(final XYDataset dataset) {
    final JFreeChart result = ChartFactory.createXYAreaChart(
        TITLE, "hh:mm:ss", "milliVolts", dataset,PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, false);
    final XYPlot plot = result.getXYPlot();
    ValueAxis domain = plot.getDomainAxis();
    domain.setAutoRange(true);

    ValueAxis range = plot.getRangeAxis();
    range.setRange(-MINMAX, MINMAX);
    return result;
}

public void start() {
    timer.start();
}

public static void main(final String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            essaijfree2 demo = new essaijfree2(TITLE);
            demo.pack();
            RefineryUtilities.centerFrameOnScreen(demo);
            demo.setVisible(true);
            demo.start();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Cross-posted [here](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=116744).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the upper margin on the domain axis:

`domain.setUpperMargin(0.5);`